# How do I add new jsp page in Spring MVC netbeans Project?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple JSP spring project in net-beans.

I want to create a new page and go to it from "index.jsp(html)".

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="newpage.jsp">
   ...
   button with submit type
</form>
```

What do I for go to newpage.jsp?

I add the newpage.jsp and run my project but Server can not find this page!!!

Is any setting to run correct project? What is this?

my project:

[image]

index page:

[image]

[image]

other page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume that if you would like to get the answer to the question if your settings are correct, you should post them as well.

Comment: Can you post the location image of those two pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is the form target is at wrong location:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="newpage.jsp">
```

You see at the address bar before submit its:

```
Test/index.html
```

After submit its:

```
Test/newpage.jsp
```

Whereas, the jsp location is under `WEB-INF/jsp/newpage.jsp`.

In general you should submit form to controller, use the `InternalResourceViewResolver` to point out the pages under `WEB-INF` in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

You can also go through this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html)

Comment: please explain for me step to step that I must do it. Thank U